# call and view information in sharepoint 2013 profile

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, user-profile

how can I use Profile synchronization  in order to provides a reliable way to synchronize groups and user profile information that is stored in the SharePoint Server 2013 profile database together with information that is stored in directory services across the enterprise especially non-Microsoft identity solution for example we stored human resource information in another app which is not based on sharepoint and has .net platform with sql server database Is it possible to read information of each user from database and show them in user profile if it is possible how can we do it ?

Comment: Are you (very) comfortable with using PowerShell?

Comment: yes I am comfortable with  PowerShell

Comment: Then: https://www.google.nl/search?q=powershell+sharepoint+userprofiles

Answer (score 0):

The out of the box way to do this is to use the BCS to create a External Content Type to the user data and ensure that there is a identity filed like email or user id that SharePoint can match to the user. Then create a secondary import connection in the User Profile Service to import the data and update the User Profile.

I have done this exact thing with PeopleSoft on Oracle, SAP, etc all running on different platforms that SharePoint.

Comment: we just need to run  BCS or need programming too?

Comment: You need to configure the External Content Type. It's all XML, so I don't count that as "programming". You do have to know a bit of SQL to create the queries.